# Dialogflow Knowledge (beta feature)

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, google-natural-language

I am trying to create FAQ using Dialogflow Knowledge. Ideally, either the conversation intent or FAQ must trigger. When I type in the FAQ, it does fetch the response from knowledge base but at the same time it also triggers a intent for slot filling.

How can I resolve this to trigger either FAQ (if found in knowledge base) or intent  (if no FAQ exists in knowledge base, for the given threshold).

Regards.

Comment: can you post screenshot of the response, ideally it should return only one response either it will match intent or FAQ based on your settings.

Answer (score 2):

For my bot, I preferred knowledge base answers for response. for that I set the preference more towards Knowledge base like this:
[image]

Also, I didn't created any separate intent to capture slots. Only using the default that is generated while creating the knowledge base. There is also no webhook enabled for my agent.

Comment: what should be the path of knowledge base ? Is it just the knowledge base name ?

Comment: didn't get your question?

Comment: const knowledgeBaseFullName = `the full path of your knowledge base, e.g my-Gcloud-project/myKnowledgeBase`;

What should i specify here ?

Comment: @dennyjohn you get the knowledgeBaseFullName when you create the knowledge base. it is different than the display name you enter in dialogflow dashboard.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56144918/3949639