# Why does Dialogflow nodejs sdk "detect Intent with Knowledge Base" method responds with null ? ( V2Beta)

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am integrating the `Dialogflow Nodejs sdk` into my application to detect the knowledge base intent with the help of the following document [nodejs-dialoglowflow-detect-knowledgebase-intent](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/samples/detect.v2beta1.js).

Below is my query request

```
const request = {
session: sessionPath,
queryInput: {
  text: {
    // The query to send to the dialogflow agent
    text: message,
    // The language used by the client (en-US)
    languageCode: 'en-US',
  },
},
queryParams: {
  knowledgeBaseNames: ['projects/my-project-id/knowledgeBases/my-knowledge-base-name'],
},
```

};

When I test the FAQ in dialogflow console it works, but when I try to do the same with `Dialoglflow Nodejs SDK`, the `knowledgeAnswers` object from dialogflow response is null.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because of the incorrect value in `knowledgeBaseNames` property. 
When you create a knowledge base it returns below response:

```
{
  "name": "projects/project-id/knowledgeBases/NDA4MTM4NzE2MjMwNDUxMjAwMA",
  "displayName": "knowledge-base-display-name"
}
```

`knowledgeBaseNames` property accepts the array of `name`. It is different than `displayName`.

In case you have created the Konwledgebase form Dialogflow dashboard, you won't see this detail in the dashboard. However, Dialogflow SDKs Provide APIs to get the list of knowledgebase of an agent. Node js V2Beta1 SDK has a method [`projects.knowledgeBases.list`](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.knowledgeBases/list), which, when given a project name, will list all of the knowledge bases along with their display name and their name. You can send the list of names into the detect intent request.

If your use case only requires knowing the ID for the knowledge base then you can get if from "Try it out" section of the Dialogflow console. Type a question you have added in knowledgebase and click on `diagnostic info`. It will show the dialogflow response in JSON. Look for the `knowledgeAnswers` object. The knowledgebase ID is the part of `source` property as mentioned below:

```
"knowledgeAnswers": {
            "answers": [{
                "source": "projects/project-id/knowledgeBases/knowledgebase-id/documents/document-id"
            }]
}
```

Comment: The answer isn't clear in what's it's directing OP to actually do.  I have a similar problem and have used the "name" value from the diagnostic info that Google shares from testing inside the console, and it still doesn't work via the SDK.

Comment: For me the issue was that I was using the /v2/ API version instead of the /v2beta1/ version