# Dialogflow knowledbase works and responds in the 'try it now" console but not on integration kommunicate

Tags: dialogflow-es, kommunicate

My Dialogflow knowledge base intent is detected when I ask questions withing the knowledge base document while in the dialogflow console try it now and works well in facebook too. But when integrated kommunicate, if i ask a same question, it defaults to fallback intent and responds with fallback response. What could be the cause. I increased the knowledge base slider to strongest.

[Screenshot of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si9BK.png)

Answer (score 1):

Kommunicate supports the knowledgebase feature of Dialogflow. However, This feature is disabled by default because it is in the beta phase. 
If you want to enable this feature you can contact to Kommunciate support team at `support@kommunicate.io` with the knowledgebase Ids and bot Id.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56144918/3949639) answer to get the knowledgebase id from Dialogflow.